# Dynamic Event Handling React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using 2 different functions to do the same thing and I am trying to merge them into one, but I am unable to do so. I read such a thing can be achieved through Dynamic Event Handling. I have tried but I failed.

**Below are the two functions I want to merge**

```js
 updateProfValue(index, value) {
    this.props.profValue(index, value);
  }

 updatePersonalVaue(index, value) {
    this.props.persValue(index, value);
  }
```

And I want them to use in this component dynamically.

```js
{
  abc.map((item, index) => { <
    FCW
    changeHandler = {
      this.updatePersonalVaue
    }
    defaultOption = {
      item.value
    }
    index = {
      index
    }
    key = {
      item.Cn
    }
    name = {
      item.dN
    }
    required = {
      item.r
    }
    />);
  })
}

{
  xyz.map((item, index) => { <
        FCW
        changeHandler = {
          this.updateProfVaue
        }
        defaultOption = {
          item.value
        }
        index = {
          index
        }
        key = {
          item.Cn
        }
        name = {
          item.dN
        }
        required = {
          item.r
        }
        />);
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to archive. Perhaps you can do it using if statement in the merged function.